Azure Managed Identity SQL Connection Failing Randomly with "Login Failed for User '<token-identified principal>'"
I'm encountering a random issue with my Azure Function App (dotnet 8 Isolated) where the SQL connection using Azure Managed Identity is failing. I'm using DefaultAzureCredential for token generation and the connection is working fine most of the time (like 90%). But from time to time I'm getting the following exception.
Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Login failed for user '<token-identified principal>'. at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction) at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose) at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TryRun(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean& dataReady) at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.Run(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj) at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.CompleteLogin(Boolean enlistOK) at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.AttemptOneLogin(ServerInfo serverInfo, String newPassword, SecureString newSecurePassword, Boolean ignoreSniOpenTimeout, TimeoutTimer timeout,

I've ensured that the managed identity has the necessary permissions and the connection string is correctly configured. What could be causing this issue and how can I resolve it?
I have updated the Azure.Identity.dll to latest (1.13.1)

Can you provide your code in the question?

You may get a better response if you show the code and/or the ARM template

@Anuradha Malalasena Have you tried this MS DOC.


Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Login failed for user 'token-identified principal'.

You could be getting this error due to the following reasons :-

As you have mentioned that you are using connection string a long with the managed identity in function app then consider resetting the connection string and make sure you are using correct username and password in it.

I also got the same error but post resetting the connection string Server=tcp:{server_name}.database.windows.net,1433;Initial Catalog={database_name};Persist Security Info=False;User ID={username};Password={your_password};MultipleActiveResultSets=False;Encrypt=True;TrustServerCertificate=False;Connection Timeout=30; in Environment variables then, it worked for me.





You can also establish a connection to the database without using connection string.

[FunctionName("SqlConnection")]
public static async Task<IActionResult> Run(
[HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "get", Route = null)] HttpRequest req,
ILogger _logger)
{
    var credential = new DefaultAzureCredential();
    var connectionString = new SqlConnectionStringBuilder
    {
        DataSource = "myserver.database.windows.net",
        InitialCatalog = "mydatabase",
    }.ToString();

    using var sqlConnection = new SqlConnection(connectionString);

    try
    {
        sqlConnection.AccessToken = credential.GetToken(
        new TokenRequestContext(new[] { "https://database.windows.net/.default" })
        ).Token;

        await sqlConnection.OpenAsync();
        _logger.LogInformation("Connection to SQL Database established successfully.");
        return new OkObjectResult("Connected successfully!");
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        _logger.LogError($"Error connecting to SQL Database: {ex.Message}");
        return new StatusCodeResult(StatusCodes.Status500InternalServerError);
    }
}


Grant the below permissions to managed identity in the database.

CREATE USER [identity_name] FROM EXTERNAL PROVIDER;
ALTER ROLE db_datareader ADD MEMBER [identity_name];
ALTER ROLE db_datawriter ADD MEMBER [identity_name];
ALTER ROLE db_ddladmin ADD MEMBER [identity_name];
GO

